# Issues with FOR Loop in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have been using the below query to bulk insert data into collection using FOR loop. When I iterate the loop for 10000 times it fails after some iterations mainly between 5k & 8k.

```
db.OneCo.drop()
var bulk = db.OneCo.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var p = 0.1, q = 0.6
    for (i = 1; i < 10000; i++) {
        bulk.insert({
            _id : i + p,
            Act : NumberInt(i),
            sqr : (i + p) * (i + p),
            M2 : (i + p) * 2,
            M3 : (i + p) * 3
        });
        bulk.insert({
            _id : i + q,
            Act : NumberInt(i),
            sqr : (i + q) * (i + q),
            M2 : (i + q) * 2,
            M3 : (i + q) * 3
        });
    }
    bulk.execute();
print(i)
```

Ideally, above code should insert 19998 docs in the collection, however, I see irregular count of docs inserted every time I execute the code, mostly somewhere between 11000 & 15000. 
Can someone help what is wrong with the code?

Comment: any reason for failure?

Comment: It is not actually failing with an error. The code execution succeeds but I could not see all the docs inserted in the collection.

Comment: Did you try to create lower bulks? Like range of 1000? Also if you create 20 bulks with 1000 items, do you wait one after another, so they are not executed all at once?

Comment: I do not know to create lower bulks. But when I see **bulk.getOperations()** I see a batch of 1000 docs being pushed in one instance. I don't think all are executed at once because I have used **initializeOrderedBulkOp()**. Let me know if my understanding is right.

Comment: I have no issues with this code adds `19998` records in 2 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put my code in a function and executed the function it has processed all the docs.
Not sure what is the problem with direct query.
I think it is an issue with RoboMongo Interface where it starts the loop to insert docs in the collection but in the case of function Robomongo sends the command to mongoDB where the loop is internally opened and docs are inserted correctly.

However, this has solved my problem, so will mark it has answer after 2-3 days. I will be glad if someone can find a perfect reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

looks like some logic issue at your code.

try doing below,

take all results of i + p to array1

take all results of i + q to array2

combine both arrays and remove duplicates.

you will finally get 9330 elements only.